# Can I have a function inside a function?

Tags: c++

I am basically making a game that involves two players and I have to use functions, selections and loops to achieve it.

So, I made a function that asks user1 and user2 to input their name into the program.

My question is, if, lets say I make another function and in that function I want to have an if statement that checks the condition ... for example if (name == someFunction) then output the following etc etc.

I am writing my code below, so maybe that will make it more clear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

string getPlayerOneName();
string getPlayerTwoName();
double game(string, int, int);

int main()
{

    cout << "Let's Play Frack! " << endl << endl;
    string nameOne = getPlayerOneName();
    string nameTwo = getPlayerTwoName();
    int points = getUserInputForPoints();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

string getPlayerOneName() // -----------------------------------------------------

{
    string playerOne;
    cout << "Enter player 1's name: ";
    cin >> playerOne;
    return playerOne;
}

string getPlayerTwoName() // -----------------------------------------------------

{
    string playerTwo;
    cout << "Enter player 2's name: ";
    cin >> playerTwo;
    return playerTwo;
}

double game(string name, int tno, int dno)
{
    char roll;
    double avg = 0.0;
    cout << name << "s turn" << tno << " " << endl;
    cout << "Enter R to roll " << dno << "dice: ";
    cin >> roll;
    cout << endl;
    if (roll == 'R')
    {
        if (name == )
        {
            char ch;
            cout << "Do you want to start from zero (z) or from " << playerOne << "'s" << "score:? ";
            cin >> ch;
            if (ch == 'z')
            {
                dno = 5;
            }
        }

        cout << "Your dice are: ";
        int dno2 = dno;
    }
}
```

So for the last function, inside the if statement can i have - :

```
if (name == string getPlayerTwoName())
{
}
```

Comment: No, but that's because `== string` is a syntax error and has nothing to do with functions.

Comment: So, how do i get player two's name inside that if statement. Do i need to make another variable "playerTwo" inside that function again ?

Comment: Remove `string`.

Comment: @MantejSokhi you can make nameOne & nameTwo global variable. or pass them into game function.

Comment: You need to make the player names parameters to your `game` function so you can access them. You have several parameters already, so it's just the same as you've already done.

Comment: In C++ the best way to handle related data is to group it into classes. But I guess that you've yet to learn about that.

Comment: `if (name == string getPlayerTwoName())
{
}` --> `if (name == getPlayerTwoName())
{
}`

Comment: @shb global variables are rarely the correct answer

Comment: @AlanBirtles definitely. Looking at the code, you'll find this is not complete. game function is not being called from anywhere too. the intention was not to take the same input from the console every time. It was also suggested to pass the values.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have two somehow similar functions

```
string getPlayerOneName() // -----------------------------------------------------

{
string playerOne;
cout << "Enter player 1's name: ";
cin >> playerOne;
return playerOne;
}

string getPlayerTwoName() // -----------------------------------------------------

{
string playerTwo;
cout << "Enter player 2's name: ";
cin >> playerTwo;
return playerTwo;
}
```

and you think: 'This should be generalized into one function.'

First of all: Congratulations. You start to think like a computer scientist. (No joke.)

To achieve this, you have to identify what's actually different in these two functions.

The `string player`… variables are but this can be changed without breaking anything:

```
string getPlayerOneName() // -----------------------------------------------------

{
string player;
cout << "Enter player 1's name: ";
cin >> player;
return player;
}

string getPlayerTwoName() // -----------------------------------------------------

{
string player;
cout << "Enter player 2's name: ";
cin >> player;
return player;
}
```

There's still the different prompt text. So, this is a candidate for a function parameter:

```
string getPlayerName(const char *prompt)
{
  string player;
  cout << prompt;
  cin >> player;
  return player;
}
```

The new function `getPlayerName()` can then be called with:

```
  string nameOne = getPlayerName("Enter player 1's name: ");
  string nameTwo = getPlayerName("Enter player 2's name: ");
```

This is quite flexible because it could be used for other things than player name. (Though, in this case `getName()` would probably be the better choice.)

If this is not intended the code duplication (in call) could be reduced more, e.g.:

```
string getPlayerName(int iPlayer)
{
  string player;
  cout << "Enter player " << iPlayer << "'s name: ";
  cin >> player;
  return player;
}
```

and the calls would look like:

```
  string nameOne = getPlayerName(1);
  string nameTwo = getPlayerName(2);
```